# Continuous Replication/Realtime Syncing between On-Premise MYSQL database to Amazon RDS

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, database-migration, amazon-rds

I've currently completed a replication between my on-premise MYSQL database and an Amazon RDS Instance using AWS Database Migration Service (DMS). My challenge now is to allow them to both sync with each other realtime as opposed to doing scheduled mysql dumps. I believe continuous replication is currently supported for Microsoft SQL servers but what about MYSQL?

Comment: Potentially duplicate and I don't think there is out of the box solution.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46987638/two-way-syncing-between-local-mysql-database-and-aws-rds

Comment: Yes, RDS for MySQL supports this.  Which one is master? RDS or on-premise?  Do you have a VPN connection between your data center and the VPC where RDS is running?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot both will be masters, they will both have new records added to their databases which will have to sync in real-time. Each server will not be touching the same tables, but they have to eventually be in sync.